# How to get LIMIT on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, limit

cI'm seeking some help with my left join with a limit.

What i'm trying to do is to loop through my users and check in another table if there's problems connected to the user.

But currently I'm getting all kinds of weird results and it does not LIMIT the result for each user and it also lists column **status_link_missing = 0** even though i have told the sub query to only list **status_link_missing = 1**

So I'm stuck for now, help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT 
      a.user_id AS settings_userid
    , a.contact_interval
    , b.user_id 
    , b.notify_user 
    , b.status_host_down 
    , b.status_link_missing 
    , b.status_relnofollow 
FROM  `link_exchange_settings` a
LEFT JOIN link_exchange_links b 
  ON b.id
     = ( SELECT c.id 
         FROM link_exchange_links AS c 
         WHERE 
         b.user_id = a.user_id
         AND c.notify_user = 1 
         AND c.status_link_missing = 1 
         LIMIT 1
       )
WHERE a.allow_contact = 1
LIMIT 10
```

**Edit**

I switched **SELECT b.id to c.id now** and LIMIT works but now it only works for the first user

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this change (no reference to `b` in the subquery):

```
SELECT 
      a.user_id AS settings_userid
    , a.contact_interval
    , b.user_id 
    , b.notify_user 
    , b.status_host_down 
    , b.status_link_missing 
    , b.status_relnofollow 
FROM  `link_exchange_settings` a
LEFT JOIN link_exchange_links b 
  ON b.id
     = ( SELECT c.id                        -- changed
         FROM link_exchange_links AS c 
         WHERE 
         c.user_id = a.user_id              -- changed
         AND c.notify_user = 1 
         AND c.status_link_missing = 1
         -- ORDER BY c.something            -- optional, recommended addition
         LIMIT 1
       )
WHERE a.allow_contact = 1
-- ORDER BY a.something_else                -- optional, recommended addition
LIMIT 10 ;
```

It's also good to have `ORDER BY` when you use `LIMIT`. Unless you want indeterminate results.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube that did the trick! you saved my brain from complete failure, much appreciated!

Comment: Good to hear. This looks like a strange way to write "greatest-n-per-group" queries but I often use it in MySQL (and it's usually efficient with proper indexes.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using "c.status_link_missing = 1" in sub-query but if you will use it in WHERE clause with "AND" you will get your desired results.

In fact you have to decide and use appropriate condition in WHERE clause of main query instead of LEFT JOIN sub-query.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow Fahad, do i need to include link_exchange_links outside the sub query also?

Comment: Sorry i still don't follow, feeling kinda dumb here

Comment: Please correct the query as:
`SELECT 
      a.user_id AS settings_userid
    , a.contact_interval
    , b.user_id 
    , b.notify_user 
    , b.status_host_down 
    , b.status_link_missing 
    , b.status_relnofollow 
FROM  link_exchange_settings a
LEFT JOIN link_exchange_links b 
  ON 
(
b.user_id = a.user_id
AND
b.notify_user = 1 
AND 
b.status_link_missing = 1 
)
WHERE a.allow_contact = 1
LIMIT 10`

Comment: @John : also you should select c.id in the subquery not b.id

Comment: @ankur i tried that but second user gets nulled for some reason like the picture in my question, i don't know why.